# Extract Data from a JSON array with php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I try to extract data from an json array but always i got empty string.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ItemList>
        <Entry Item = "test1" Object = "1tset" />
        <Entry Item = "test2" Object = "2tset" />
</ItemList>
```

My Dump from XML:

```
array(1) { ["Entry"]=> array(2) 
{ [0]=> array(1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["Item"]=> string(5) "test1" ["Object"]=> string(5) "1tset" } } 
[1]=> array(1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["Item"]=> string(5) "test2" ["Object"]=> string(5) "2tset" } } } }
```

My php code:

```
$xmlString = "my.xml";
$xmlObject = simplexml_load_file($xmlString);
$xmltovar = json_decode(json_encode($xmlObject), true);


foreach($xmltovar['Entry'] as $test) {

    echo $test['Item']."<br>";
}
```

I need to get all "Item"or "Object" from ItemList->Entry Tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the encoding and decoding your `$xmltovar` is like this:

```
Array
(
    [Entry] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [Item] => test1
                            [Object] => 1tset
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [Item] => test2
                            [Object] => 2tset
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

So instead of:

```
echo $test['Item']."<br>";
```

write:

```
echo $test['@attributes']['Item']."<br>";
```

Same goes for Object.

Answer (score 0):

Your php must be look like this

```
<?php

$xmlString = "my.xml";
$xmlObject = simplexml_load_file($xmlString);
$xmltovar = json_decode(json_encode($xmlObject), true);


foreach($xmltovar['Entry'] as $test) {
    echo $test["@attributes"]['Item']."<br>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$test['@attributes']['Item'] for Item

$test['@attributes']['Object'] for Object